# search each individual word and filtering if less than x amount of characters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following mysql query to search my FAQ:

```
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq
        WHERE (`question` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR (`answer` LIKE '%".$search."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

(Yes I know I should be using PDO)

When I search for "design" for example it returns questions\answers with the word design. Example result: "How do I begin the design process?". This is perfect, however if I search for "create a design" no result will be found, which is not okay, because it's not searching for each individual word "create" "a" design". Even if this was resolved it would create another issue, php would need to omit words I'm assuming less than 4 characters to prevent "how" "do" "I" etc. from returning every FAQ result in the mysql database.

Edit: I can easily remove words less than 4 characters by using preg_replace.

Comment: Using PDO and placeholder values is long overdue for this code. What you're asking about is involving the [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). You can't do it with `LIKE`.

Comment: Let us know when you start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want your $search to be:

(`question` LIKE '%create%' AND `question` LIKE '%a%' AND `question` LIKE '%design%') OR (`answer` LIKE '%create%' AND `answer` LIKE '%a%' AND `answer` LIKE '%design%')

This will give results for a string containing all the words and not a full phrase as "%create a design%"